# Is there a option to group hours together in charts with google data studio?

Tags: looker-studio

In google data studio, I have a chart that's of  24 hours. I want these hours grouped in groups of four. Ex. [0:00-4:00] [4:00-8:00][8:00-12:00][12:00-16:00][16:00-20:00][20:00-00:00].

this is my chart now, and I only want 6 bars in total of the grouped hours and not 24.
[image: Chart now]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In your data source, you can create a new field by coding here for an example :

```
CASE
WHEN co2 IN ("00","01","02","03") THEN "[0:00-3:00]"
WHEN co2 IN ("04","05","06","07") THEN "[4:00-7:00]"
WHEN co2 IN ("08","09","10","11") THEN "[8:00-11:00]"
WHEN co2 IN ("12","13","14","15") THEN "[12:00-15:00]"
WHEN co2 IN ("16","17","18","19") THEN "[16:00-19:00]"
ELSE "[20:00-00:00]"`enter code here`
END
```